# Talend Open Studio v6.2.0, on startup throws error "Could not resolve module: org.talend.designer.business.diagram"

Tags: talend, data-integration

I have java 8 installed on ubuntu 14.04, have downloaded Talend open studio for DI v 6.2.0.
I have followed the steps to install talend for a 32 bit ubuntu box.But whenever I start the talend studio , it throws the above error.

Please find the logs;

```
!SESSION 2016-06-14 11:32:54.435 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.talend.designer.business.diagram 4 0 2016-06-14 11:32:55.465
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.talend.designer.business.diagram [9]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.10.1.v20140828-0944"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.ide [531]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.106.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.106.0.v20140812-1751"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui [222]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.105.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.106.1.v20140827-1737"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.ui.workbench [510]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"; bundle-version="0.12.1.v20140903-1023"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                            org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [664]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.9.0"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator 4 0 2016-06-14 11:32:55.471
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ui.navigator [11]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.6.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.106.0.v20140812-1751"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui [222]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.105.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.106.1.v20140827-1737"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui.workbench [510]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt
                  -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"; bundle-version="0.12.1.v20140903-1023"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                     org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [664]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.9.0"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.dnd 4 0 2016-06-14 11:32:55.488
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.dnd [14]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.106.0.v20140812-1751"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui [222]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.105.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.106.1.v20140827-1737"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui.workbench [510]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt
                  -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"; bundle-version="0.12.1.v20140903-1023"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                     org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [664]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.9.0"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.talend.repository.items.importexport.ui 4 0 2016-06-14 11:32:55.494
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.talend.repository.items.importexport.ui [15]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.106.0.v20140812-1751"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui [222]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.105.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.106.1.v20140827-1737"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui.workbench [510]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt
                  -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"; bundle-version="0.12.1.v20140903-1023"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                     org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [664]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.9.0"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Any help would be a day saver.Thanks

I tried with 6.1 version of TOS-DI . Now it throws

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/m2e/core/MavenPlugin
    at org.talend.designer.maven.tools.creator.CreateMavenBundleTemplatePom.<clinit>(CreateMavenBundleTemplatePom.java:41)
    at org.talend.designer.maven.utils.TalendCodeProjectUtil.initCodeProject(TalendCodeProjectUtil.java:45)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.java.JavaProcessorUtilities.getTalendJavaProject(JavaProcessorUtilities.java:89)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.DefaultRunProcessService.getTalendProcessJavaProject(DefaultRunProcessService.java:478)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.RunProcessService.getTalendProcessJavaProject(RunProcessService.java:335)
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.AbstractRoutineSynchronizer.getRoutineFile(AbstractRoutineSynchronizer.java:110)
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.AbstractRoutineSynchronizer.doSyncRoutine(AbstractRoutineSynchronizer.java:191)
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.AbstractRoutineSynchronizer.syncRoutine(AbstractRoutineSynchronizer.java:177)
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.JavaRoutineSynchronizer.syncRoutineItems(JavaRoutineSynchronizer.java:92)
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.JavaRoutineSynchronizer.syncAllRoutinesForLogOn(JavaRoutineSynchronizer.java:72)
    at org.talend.core.CoreService.syncAllRoutines(CoreService.java:281)
    at org.talend.core.repository.model.ProxyRepositoryFactory.logOnProject(ProxyRepositoryFactory.java:1865)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.login.LoginHelper$1.run(LoginHelper.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Comment: I'd try re-downloading the package. Also, I'd try Java 1.7. Additionally, an requirement isn't met at the last level `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt`. Is there an Eclipse version for swt? Maybe gtk and swt are not able to communicate.

Comment: Are you telling that , I should remove java 1.8 and try with java 1.7?

Comment: First, I'd look further into the issue with swt/gtk. Then, just to try it out, but the newest Talend DI Eclipse should be compatible with Java 8.